# The reason to veto in zakiur rahman lakhvi case

Tags: united-nations

Recently a veto was held in un in favour of release of convicted zakiur rahman lakhvi.Can somebody tell what was the reason given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: The decision the UN made was not about the release of Zakiur Rahman Lakhvi. The UN has no authority to decide about the release of a single person. But what the UN can do is sanction a country because of what they do or don't do.

What happened was that India put a motion into place to put sanctions on Pakistan because of their decision to release Lakhvi. Then China decided to veto this motion thus preventing the UN from taking action on Pakistan.

The reason why China decided to side with Pakistan instead of India is because China has invested in various economic projects which require the cooperation of Pakistan. Among them the [trans-continental Belt and Road Initiative](http://chinawatch.washingtonpost.com/2015/04/xis-pakistan-trip-a-boost-for-silk-road/) and the [China-Pakistan Economic Corridor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93Pakistan_Economic_Corridor). China couldn't care less about islamistic terrorism, because so far they were largely unaffected by the issue. But what China does care about are their economical interests in Pakistan. So it repeatedly used its veto power in the UN to appease Pakistan and ensure their cooperation.

Comment: But they need to give reason to peoples .what reason they give?What reason you gave is true inside view.

Comment: @Raul Why would that matter? When a country uses its veto right in the UN it does not need to give a reason. And when the media bothers them to give one, they can always make up some typical politicians wish-wash.

Comment: So it is a direct indication of unfriendliness with India.

Comment: @Raul not so much unfriendliness with India but rather friendliness with Pakistan. China doesn't want to antagonize India just because they can. They just believe that Pakistan is currently a much more valuable partner to them - so valuable that antagonizing India is worth it.

Comment: but it might have also considered indias anger over it

Comment: @Raul They certainly did, as well as possible reactions from other countries invested in the war on terror. But they considered it less important than Pakistan's anger.

Comment: can you also tell me what china meant when talking about america entering its territorial water while doing surviellence in south china sea.

Comment: @Raul Now that is a completely different topic. Please ask it as a new question.